# Flash Implicit coercion of value error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

for some reason Im getting the following error

> Implicity coercion of a value with a static type flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip

The line the error points to is "addInfoBubble(item)" below

```
for(var i:Number=0; i < MapContainer.numChildren; i++) {
    var item:DisplayObject = MapContainer.getChildAt(i);
    if(item!=null && item is MovieClip){ // make sure its a movieclip
        trace('Found movieclip');
        addInfoBubble(item);
        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, countryMouseOver);
        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, countryMouseOut);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you made sure it's a MovieClip, the compiler doesn't know that.  The variable needs to be typed as a MovieClip.

Change these 2 lines:

```
var item:DisplayObject = MapContainer.getChildAt(i);
if(item!=null && item is MovieClip){ // make sure its a movieclip
```

to

```
var item:MovieClip = MapContainer.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
if(item){
```

Comment: Hi Sean thanks heaps, so I assume "MapContainer.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip" does that only retrieve children of type MovieClip?

Comment: Yes, the `as` operator returns `null` if the left-hand operand isn't an instance of the right-hand operand.  So, the if statement will be skipped if it's not a MovieClip.

Comment: Fixed my problem as well :)